# Initialize autowired objects in TestNG unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, jmockit, injectable

So here is my code:

```
@Service("MyCode")
public class CodeImpl implements CodeI {

    @Autowired
    private CodeMapper codeMapper;

    @Autowired
    private CodeAppService codeAppService;

    @Override
    public CodePOJO getCode(String myId) {
        CodeDTO codeDTO = codeAppService.getOne(myId);
        return codeMapper.mapCode(codeDTO);
    }

}
```

And this is the Unit Test that I have written:

```
public class CodeImplTest {

    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true)
    CodeImpl codeImpl;

    @Injectable
    CodeAppService mockedCodeAppService;

    @Injectable
    CodeMapper mockedCodeMapper;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup_mocks() {
        codeImpl = new CodeImpl();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCode() throws Exception {

        final CodeDTO codeDTO = new codeDTO();
        codeDTO.setName("my name")

        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            mockedCodeAppService.getOne(anyString);
            result = codeDTO;
        }};

        CodePOJO returnedCodePOJO = codeImpl.getCode("1");
        assertThat(returnedCodePOJO, is(instanceOf(CodePOJO.class)));
        assertThat(returnedCodePOJO.getName(), is("my name"));
    }

}
```

I am getting this following uninitialized exception:

```
  java.lang.AssertionError: 
      Expected: is "my name"
      but: was null

  at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)   
  at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)    
  at com.dev.impl.CodeImplTest.testGetCode(CodeImplTest.java:74)
```

I have tried searching it on the forum but can't any answer to work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try the API documentation for `@Tested`, it has the answer.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? I tried reading through so many posts and docs, and still it doesn't work for me. Either I fell into NPE or above exception.

Comment: Being more specific, see the second sentence of the second paragraph in the API documentation for `@Tested`: "By default, automatic creation occurs just before a test method is executed, provided the tested field remains null at such time; ...".

Answer (score 1):

You only prepared behaviour for `codeAppService.getOne()` but in your code, the result from that call is then passed to `codeMapper.mapCode()`.

I would try:

```
new NonStrictExpectations() {{
    mockedCodeAppService.getOne(anyString);
    result = codeDTO;
    mockedCodeMapper.mapCode(codeDTO);
    result = codeDTO;
}};
```

Comment: I don't need to have the second one because that's the behavior logic that I am testing in my unit test.

Comment: The way you have your test defined, by putting @Tested on class CodeImpl, what you are testing is the fact that when calling getCode("1") a call to codeAppService.getOne(myId); and then a call to codeMapper.mapCode(codeDTO); are done. So you DO need the second one. If you want to test CodeMapper, then you need to create a new test for that class.